# Give the Attribute Error while importing xlwt

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, xlwt, odoo-11

When I Import xlwt directly just Example ,

```
try:
 import xlwt
 from xlwt import Borders
except ImportError:
 xlwt = None
```

then working fine with

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
```

But when I used the python lib for xlwt :~ https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/#files and put into custom like this

```
from odoo.addons.inventory.python_lib import xlwt
```

and calling the

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
```

That time error popup

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Workbook'
```

So how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

It seems `xlwt` library not available in your system. Try with following command to installed it.

```
pip3 install xlwt
```

Comment: Thank you for ans but I will check that before and its install already and "xlwt.__VERSION__" and version is 1.3.0

Comment: Can you check it location of that package. It should be under `python 3.x` version. If not then copy paste from `python 2.7`